# PostgreSQL - SELECT INTO ARRAY

Tags: postgresql, multidimensional-array

I've been scouring this site to find out how to dump the results of a select statement to an array, so I can iterate through an array. However I have not been lucky enough to find a simple example. The code below is an example of what I did. However I cannot figure out how to do this with an array. Only a row construct. Whenever I attempt to assign the query results to an array I get this subquery error (i.e. something like "array := (select...from sometable)", which I understand, but there has to be a way to do it. Thanks in advance. (Addition: PSeudo-Code for what I prefer beneath this actual code).

```
DO
$$
DECLARE
    nRowCount          bigint;
    i                  record;
BEGIN

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS companies_sample_db_temp;
CREATE TABLE companies_sample_db_temp (
col1     varchar
, col2     varchar
, col3     varchar
);

INSERT INTO companies_sample_db_temp VALUES ('McDonalds','Los Angeles','CA');
INSERT INTO companies_sample_db_temp VALUES ('Starbucks','Seattle','WA');
INSERT INTO companies_sample_db_temp VALUES ('Oracle','San Francisco','CA');

-- SELECT * FROM companies_sample_db_temp;

FOR i IN
  with a as
  (
    SELECT
    ARRAY[col1::text
          , col2::text
          , col3::text                    
    ] as coltext
    FROM companies_sample_db_temp AS my_arr
  )
  select row_number() over(), coltext from a
LOOP
--    RAISE INFO 'nRowCount: %', nRowCount;
     RAISE INFO 'Array Info: %', i.coltext[1];
END LOOP;

END
$$;

/*********** Pseudo Code of what I'd rather do *******************/
DO
$$
DECLARE
    -- Assign results of this query to an array
    my_arr := SELECT col1, col2,col3 FROM companies_sample_db_temp;
    i                  record;

BEGIN
-- Loop through an "array" not a table using a select statement.
FOR i IN
    -- Iterate through each row of the array
    my_arr[i] -- Row from the select query
    LOOP
       -- Display an elements within a single array row
       RAISE INFO 'Array Info: %', my_arr[i][1]; -- col1
       RAISE INFO 'Array Info: %', my_arr[i][2]; -- col2
       RAISE INFO 'Array Info: %', my_arr[i][3]; -- col3
END LOOP;
END $$;
```

Hope this clears up the question.

Comment: Why do you want an array and not a set of rows? This is SQL, sets of rows are the normal thing to loop over - or, preferably, operate on with SQL statements and let the DBMS decide whether looping is even necessary...

Comment: Very good question. The reason I'd rather use an array is due to performance. I'll be the 1st to say I may be wrong on this one, since I'm still a newb. However in other languages, memory variables are usually significantly faster than recordsets or tables. If this is not the case, please let me know where I can find information on this subject (if you're familiar with any). I haven't had much luck on this.

Comment: Actually, record sets and tables are very frequently faster than "memory variables" (I assume you mean application logic outside of the database here), unless the software is designed by "web scale" developers who think a database is a giant array. (Admittedly, the latter is a frequent occurrence.)

Answer (score 2):

Given that your reasoning for attempting this is "performance", consider the following:

1. Tables and rows (or, in non-SQL terms, relations and tuples) are Postgres's bread and butter; if they weren't efficient, it would be a pretty poor DBMS.
2. "Premature optimisation" is generally counter-productive: the more time you spend early on things you think *might* have performance impact, the less time you have later to fix things which *do* have performance impact. If you're encapsulating a process in a function, that's a pretty good place to emphasise simplicity and maintainability, because you can substitute a new implementation later if you find it is actually giving you problems.
3. It's pretty rare for a DBMS to even *have* array types, and any problem that seems to need loops in a database function can usually be re-framed as an operation against a set of data, and the solution turned into SQL proper. The DBMS *might* decide to use a loop internally, but 99% of the time, it's better at making that decision than you.
4. You mention "memory variables"; I'm not quite sure what you mean by that (everything's in memory when it's being operated on), but it sounds like you're making quite in-depth assumptions about how different data types will work "under the hood". A dynamic array and a set of records are both complex data structures which will need to be managed; there's no fundamental reason in *any* language why one would be more efficient, except that languages tend to be optimised for certain cases. (And thus see point 1.)

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! You gave me a lot to consider. By "memory variables" I meant outside of the SQL data structure. In a non-SQL programming language array loops put SQL loops to shame in performance. Once the data reaches a certain size, it doesn't matter of course, but it seems like you knew where I was going with that.I suppose if PostgreSQL does not optimize for arrays there would certainly be no advantage for my particular situation. So you've help me resolve the whole idea.